# Listener(s) for array of buttons

Tags: android

For my own practice I am a creating an array of 3 buttons in the instance field and i would like all of them to have setOnClickListeners,which allow each button to change the BackGround Color of a text View.Can any person please guide me towards the right direction.Here is my code:

```
         public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      Button b = {(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1), 
                  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2),
                   (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3),};

     TextView tv;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

   for(int i=0; i < b.length;i++){





    b[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(butt[0].isPressed()){
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }


            if(b[1].isPressed()){
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
            if(b[2].isPressed()){
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                }

                }
               });


               }
            }

       }
```

Comment: You're setting a listener for a button. So when that button is pressed, include *only* the code you want to run on that specific button click.

Comment: `Button b = ...` should be `Button[] b = ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't declaring an `Array` for your `Buttons`. I'm not sure what this would do or if it would even compile but I wouldn't think so

```
Button b = {(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1), 
              (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2),
               (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3),};
```

Change it to

```
Button[] b = {(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1), 
              (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2),
               (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3),};
```

Also, this code has to go after `setcontentView()` or you will get a `NPE` since your `Buttons` exist in your `layout` and your `layout` doesn't exist until you inflate it by calling `setContentView()`.

You can declare your `Array` before `onCreate()` but you can't initialize them until you inflate your `layout`

So you can do something like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  Button[] b = new Button[3];  //initialize as an array

 TextView tv;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

b = {(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1), 
          (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2),
           (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3),};  //add buttons AFTER calling setContentView()
...
```

**Edit  Since @pragnani deleted his answer I will edit with a bit of it that is a good idea**

You can simplify your logic by choosing which `Button` was clicked with a `switch` by doing something like below in your `for loop`

```
b[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   / v is the button that was clicked

        switch (v.getId())    //so we get its id here
        {
             case (R.id.button1):
             tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
             break;
             case (R.id.button2):
             tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
             break;
             case (R.id.button3):
             tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
             break;
        }
```

Comment: @HRo I have edited my answer with a little bit more that will make it easier...per pragnani's answer that he deleted